# subprocess.call() exec command in bash but I'm using zsh?

Tags: python

Im using Ubuntu 20 with zsh. When I using subprocess.call, it always using bash to exec command but not zsh. How should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it uses `sh` regardless of which shell is your login shell.

There is a keyword argument to select a different shell, but you should generally run as little code as possible in a subshell; mixing nontrivial shell script with Python means the maintainer has to understand both languages.

```py
whatever = subprocess.run(
    'echo $SHELL', 
    shell=True, executable='/usr/bin/zsh',
    check=True)
```

(This will echo your login shell, so the output would be `/usr/bin/zsh` even if you ran this without `executable`, or with Bash instead.)

In many situations, you should [avoid `shell=True` entirely if you can.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: For (much) more around this topic, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538